# Can I use a voltage divider and a multiplier to power a 12V component from a 5V supply?

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider

My idea was to use a the two points in a voltage divider circuit (5V and let's say 2.4V), feed those through a multiplier to power a 12V component. Is this possible? Any problems that may be encountered?

EDIT: I am limited to a 5V supply.

Comment: I'm wondering if it would be better to just multiply the voltage to 15V and use a linear regulator to bring it down to 12V. I haven't done the calculations but wouldn't a voltage divider change its output voltage depending on load?

Comment: @tangrs Yes, a voltage divider will change its output voltage depending on the load.

Comment: To make the answers you're getting clearer, the multiplier would need to be powered by 12v or more to do what you want it to do.  I.e.,this isn't possible

Answer (score 1):

Any circuit that will perform any *actual* operations on a voltage must have a supply that is at least as great as the smallest result. So in order to mulitply 5V and 2.4V you'd need a 12V supply to begin with.

Use a boost regulator instead.

Comment: Your first statement is not exactly true. A switched capacitor convertor like a LMC7660 can take a supply voltage and double it, albeit with a small current sourcing ability.

Comment: @MattYoung: I'm reasonably sure the asker wanted to take their 5V and multiply it by 2.4V rather than put it through an actual voltage multiplier or other mechanism that would work. Because 5*2.4=12.

Answer (score 0):

From your reasoning it seems that you see electronics in a very mathematical way: a division operation followed by a multiplication. Although there are parts of electronics that deals with such things (signal processing, for example), here we are talking about power supplies and the things are not so "simple".

A voltage divider is extremely simple (just two resistors), but is very power inefficient. On the other hand voltage "multiplication" is not easy at all when the voltage you want to multiply is DC (for AC you just use a transformer).

Anyway, as also @Ignacio said, you could use a boost regulator chip.

I'll add that you will be better off, probably, by using an already built DC-DC boost converter module, instead of designing one yourself. They are cheap, reliable and very efficient. Nowadays they are also very tiny, so they don't take much board space.

For example one like [this](https://www.pololu.com/product/2117) or others like the ones in [this list from the same manufacturer](https://www.pololu.com/category/132/step-up-voltage-regulators).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I misunderstood the question when I posted the original comment. No you can't multiply the voltage between two different points on a circuit to give you a bigger voltage.

However, if your project already has a micro-controller capable of driving a PWM signal (which I'm guessing is a possibility since you're working with 5V), what you can do is to create a [Dickson multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Voltage_multiplier#Dickson_charge_pump) that will multiply your 5V supply to a 15V supply (minus diode losses). You take that output and put it through a 12V linear voltage regulator to give you 12V output. This can be a simple way of boosting your 5V to 12V if you already have a means of getting PWM output.

Here's a schematic of a very basic one that could work. You could improve efficiency and the current delivering capabilities by using Schottky diodes and a LDO regulator.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYrUU5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For an idea on how this circuit works, see [Dave Jone's excellent video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I4ED_8cuVTU) explaining it.

If you don't have a way of generating a PWM signal or if the voltage multiplier isn't able to source the amount of current you need in your 12V peripheral, you could of course, use a boost regulator as suggested in the other answers.